Unable to add an A record to CoreDNS on K3S cluster
I am running 1 master and 2 worker nodes on virtualbox with vagrant, and I have several other VMs that are running some other utilities like a git server. I want to let my pods access the git server, but I am unable to do so with CoreDNS. Since I am using K3S, I followed this guide and from the one from microsoft, to summarize, they use a configmap coredns-custom, and use setup the needed host plugin
coredns-custom.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: coredns-custom
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  default.server: |
    gitea.local {
        hosts {
              192.168.56.41 gitea.local
              fallthrough
        }
    }

vagrant@control1:~$ kubectl run -it --rm --restart=Never --image=infoblox/dnstools:latest dnstools
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
dnstools# nslookup gitea.local
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

The connection itself is okay between VMs
vagrant@control1:~$ ping gitea.local
PING gitea.local (192.168.56.41) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from gitea.local (192.168.56.41): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.793 ms
64 bytes from gitea.local (192.168.56.41): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.302 ms
^C
--- gitea.local ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1028ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.302/0.547/0.793/0.245 m

What bugs me is that .server does not work, and .override errors out since I cannot have 2 hosts plugins defined.
